# What means "Post Merged (destination)" in the revision history?

Tags: support, revisions

Time to post my first question on Meta...

[This question](https://superuser.com/q/593828/195224) has two revisions, where the second one is only 5 minutes newer (9:13 vs. 9:18am). However, when I answered the question some hours later (2:00pm), I am absolutely sure that the **first** revision was displayed and there were only two other answers (mardavi and Matthew).

Some time later, I opened that question again and saw the edited question and also another answer (by Stefan Seidel), posted much earlier (9.58am).

This strikes me, especially in that case, as my answer does not fit very good to the revised questions... and Stefan Seidel had already a similar idea -- and even wrote a much better step-by-step guide. (Oh, and while writing that, s/b converted his up- in a downvote `:(` as I was so keen to add a disclaimer that my answer applies only to the first image, i.e. the first revision. Probably I better had deleted it...)

Now there are two additional, identical entries in the revision history:

```
Post Merged (destination) from superuser.com/questions/593912/…      occurred 3 hours ago
```

I suppose only since that time (2:30pm) the second revision was visible and also assume (from their answers) that mardavi and Matthew weren't aware of the changes neither.

So, finally **my question**: What does "Post Merged (destination)" mean and why was the second revision (and the first answer) not visible to all right from 9:18am on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Post merged (destination)* means that another question (`593912`) was merged into this one (`593828`). The original question (*source* we could call it) gets closed and deleted, and all answers are moved over.

The user posted essentially the same question on both Super User and Stack Overflow, and the latter was migrated here. *You originally answered the question that is now deleted*, see [your answer's revision history](https://superuser.com/posts/593924/revisions).

Stefan's answer is the only one that wasn't moved over from the now deleted duplicate question during the merge. The three other answers, including yours, were moved:

- [Matthew's answer](https://superuser.com/posts/593918/revisions) (merged)
- [your answer](https://superuser.com/posts/593924/revisions) (merged)
- [mardavi's answer](https://superuser.com/posts/593913/revisions) (merged and even migrated from SO)
- [Stefan's answer](https://superuser.com/posts/593844/revisions)

That's why Stefan's answer and the edit to the question didn't exist in your timeline when you posted your answer: You originally answered the following, different question:

> ### Allocating free space to existing partition with Gparted
>
> I have lots of unallocated space but I can't grow my /dev/sda1/ partition.
> [image]

Comment: Ah, I was confused that when I clicked the link in the "Post Merged" (`593912`) entry I ended up with the same question in the very same revision. I somehow expected to see the version before it was merged, but if it gets deleted after merging, this is of course not possible. That makes sense now, thanks for clarifying!